# Unity 2D: Кастомная физика

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

У меня есть некое тело (Круг). Оно должно двигатся при колизии с другими телами.
Круг не имеет `Rigidbody` (Небольшой challenge). Он должен отбиваться от других тел согласно правило отбивания света ( Угол отбивания равен углу падения).Но в некоторых случаях угол просчитывается неверно, и круг проходит сквозь другое тело. Что же делать?
Вот код тела:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

public bool ballIsActive,r,col;
private Vector3 ballPosition,velocity,bal,j;
public AudioClip hitsound;
public GameObject playerObject;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") { 
        bal = new Vector3 (velocity.x, velocity.y, 0) + new Vector3 (collision.rigidbody.velocity.x, 0, 0); //учитываем скорость игрока
        foreach(ContactPoint2D contact in collision.contacts){
            velocity = Vector3.Reflect (bal ,contact.normal); //Отбиваем траекторию относительно нормали
        }
    } else {
        foreach(ContactPoint2D contact in collision.contacts){
            velocity = Vector3.Reflect (velocity ,contact.normal); 
        }
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);
    }
}
void Start () {

    ballIsActive = false;
    r = true;
    col = true; 
    ballPosition = new Vector3 (0, -1.58f, 0); //Начальная позиция

}

void Update () {


    if (r){

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) == true) {

        velocity = new Vector3(2.0f,2.0f,0f);
        transform.position = new Vector3 ((ballPosition.x + velocity.x * 2.3f * Time.deltaTime), (ballPosition.y + velocity.y * 2.3f * Time.deltaTime), 0);//Просчет движения
        ballPosition = transform.position;
        ballIsActive = !ballIsActive;
        r=false;
            }
        }
    if (ballIsActive) {
            transform.position = new Vector3 ((ballPosition.x + velocity.x * 2.3f * Time.deltaTime), (ballPosition.y + velocity.y * 2.3f * Time.deltaTime), 0);
            ballPosition = transform.position;
        }

        if (ballIsActive && transform.position.y < -4.5f) { //если круг упал ниже игрока
        ballIsActive = !ballIsActive;
            ballPosition.x = playerObject.transform.position.x;
            ballPosition.y = -2f;
            transform.position = ballPosition;
            velocity = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f) ;
            playerObject.SendMessage ("TakeLife");
        r = true;
        }
 }
}
```

P.S. Когда другое тело(не круг) не двигается все проходит идеально, малейшее движение во время колизии, и круг проходит сквозь тело.

Comment: Тело отбивается от других тел согласно закону сохранения импульса и с учетом формы коллайдеров. Думаю, ошибка здесь в том, что вы пытаетесь вручную написать физику столкновений, в то время как она уже реализована в Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Хоть вы и не используете `Rigidbody`, но тем не менее все расчеты завязаны на `PhysX` и поэтому простейший способ это попробовать настроить параметры физики. Основные находятся в меню `Edit/ProjectSettings/Physics 2D`. Подергайте посмотрите на эффект.

Еще важный параметр это время между итерациями расчета физики, его надо искать в `Edit/ProjectSettings/Time`, здесь нас интересует конкретный параметр 'Fixed Timestep`.

Также ваша проблема может быть в том, что вы используете расчеты своей вариации физики в `Update`, который вызывается в момент перерисовке кадра. А вам надо переместить его в `FixedUpdate` в котором выполняется расчет всех коллизий.